# Manga that starts off as fantasy but transitions to sci-fi

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a few years ago, it was a fantasy world setting but later it becomes sci-fi. The main character is fueled by revenge and his world is in a simulation. I don’t know any more sorry if it’s too vague.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: What do you mean by "his world is in a simulation"? Was the whole world illusionary?

Comment: This has so little detail it's impossible to be certain, but it's probably LV999 no Murabito.